# Bitcoin wallet on smart phone drains battery a lot?

Tags: bitcoin-wallet-app, android, spv

I downloaded Android Bitcoin Wallet (version 6.17) on my android phone, and realized that the app drains battery a lot. The system showed 40% of battery was used to the wallet.

- Does anyone have same issue?
- Or is this happen to other different Bitcoin wallets?
- Or should I kill the process after I open the app?

If Bitcoin Wallet drains battery a lot compared to other apps like Whatsapp, Facebook that run background, the wallet is not suitable to smart phone...

Comment: if its downloading the blockchain so I think its a usual behavior

Comment: @Adam After synced blockchain, it happens.

Comment: @NateEldredge Yeah you are right, so I edited the wallet name, not core wallet.

Answer (score -1):

I never tried the android version but from my experience from the desktop version, when you run the core, the bitcoin core will attempt to connect to another peer, when it received it, it will verify the transaction using your CPU which causes more power draw

Comment: Thanks, but I rather want to know the wallet for smart phone.

Comment: SPV clients work very differently from full nodes like Bitcoin Core, so I don't think this answer is really relevant.

Comment: @YuyaOgawa if you need a wallet, try to use blockchain or coinbase

Comment: @NateEldredge I mean I never tried the mobile version of it so I just give my best answer but it still bitcoin core so it might need to do a transaction verification

Comment: I think OP is talking about some other wallet app, because there is no version of Bitcoin Core for Android.

Comment: @NateEldredge oh ok I see